# Unable to create git .lock file - File name too long

Tags: git, git-svn

I need to convert large svn repo into git. I run `git svn clone`, it works about 30 hours, and then this error occurs:

```
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/svn/trunk@26379------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/svn/trunk@26379------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------': Unable to create '/usr/local/svn2git_branches/repo/.git/refs/remotes/svn/trunk@26379------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.lock': File name too long
update-ref -m r23592 refs/remotes/svn/trunk@26379------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ a68b4ec92e6f0033997c7d6242770567274c5d84: command returned error: 128
```

`git svn fetch` leads to same result.

Workaround?

*Upd.* I run this in Ubuntu in docker container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filename too long in git for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)

Comment: But I'm run this on Ubuntu (in docker container). In windows it work very slow.

Comment: It may be the container you are using, at least this is what the link I gave suggests.

Comment: Ok. In suggested link problem about long file name that under source control. In my case it is lock file name. I'll try to use this not in container, or another file system, or may be in windows later. Also without all branches, trunk firstly, then branch by branch in different git repos, after merge that repos. May be some of this will work :)

Comment: looks like 256 bytes (or so) [limitation for path element on Linux](http://serverfault.com/a/9548). I have no idea why git-svn tries to create such reference

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion and you only use Git from then on, or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Answer (score 0):

Try the same conversion (assuming this is a one-time import) [SubGit](https://subgit.com/)

It should be more robust to path length issues (even on Ubuntu).
Worst case: you can still [skip a problematic revision and resume the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42500220/6309).